# How to add new input to html document on input typing using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to add dynamic input.

I have one input already created and if someone write something into it, it will add new input below it and if again some one write something into newly created input, it will call the same jquery and generate another input below and so on. ( same like google's contact form for address and email )

How can I do this.

I have tried this but it is giving me for each keypress new input and also for newly created input it is not working

```js
var counter = 2;
$("input[id^='textbox']").keypress(function () {
  if (counter>10){
    alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
    return false;
  }

  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

  newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                             '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                             '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
  counter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Textbox #1 : </label>
    <input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While you might be new to JavaScript, or HTML, you need to first make a credible attempt at implementing your own solution and then, *if* you have problems, come back show your "*[MCVE]*" code and explain the problems you're having. We'll happily help you with your problems, but asking us to do it for you isn't what we're here for. And if you want guidance as to how this might be implemented then that's off-topic because we don't offer, or recommend, off-site resources whether tutorials, libraries or plugins.

Comment: You should trying something and then ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handler to new input. Also check if parent of typing text is `last-child`, then add new row.

```js
$(document).on("keyup change", "input[id^='textbox']", function(){
    if ($(this).parent().is(":last-child") && $(this).val() != ""){
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 2;
        $("#TextBoxesGroup").append('<div id="TextBoxDiv'+index+'"><label>Textbox #'+index+' : </label><input type="textbox" id="textbox'+index+'" ></div>');
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label>
        <input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great. But one small issue if I am pressing tab to go to the generated textbox, it again generates new textbox.

Comment: @MahekShah Good mention. Fixed.